# JS errors and "broken" site features

Tags: support, bug, status-norepro, notification-bar

I stumbled on a weird bug that causes this JS error:

```
notify is not defined
$(function() { notify.showMessages(msgArray); });
```

This stops javascript processing and thus breaks a LOT of things. For example writing this very post I have no preview, no WYSIWYG editor, the padding-top of the page wrong, and countless other issues.

This is both a bug report and support request. **I haven't found a way to "reverse" the effects of the bug yet, so try this at your own risk.**

Steps:

- This probably won't work if you already have a `Disciplined` badge.
- Delete one of your posts with a score of 3 or higher.
- Wait until the notification bar appears telling you that you won the badge. Do not close it. Ignore it completely.
- Undelete your post.
- Visit another page.

I'm not sure if it will happen to everyone, or it's a more tricky race condition or similar. I can't try again since I can get the badge only once (and especially since I can't "undo" the bug, as mentioned).

Besides the bug report, I really need help to fix this. I can't post comments. I can't do a LOT of things. :S

This is what I tried so far:

- Log out, log in
- Try to delete my post again, but since I already got the badge (which was not removed), the notification bar doesn't appear anymore.

---

**EDIT**: Just so you know I wasn't gaming the system to get the badge, I was simply taking a screenshot for [my answer on this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14117/delete-inside-first-20-minutes-should-permanently-delete/62720#62720) :)

Comment: *points and laughs*

Comment: Kop, if you haven't fixed it, comment here so we know that it is still a bug.

Comment: http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/62725/js-errors-and-broken-site-features

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When loading a page here on Meta, are you still seeing this javascript error?

What browser are you using?

The `notify` object is a part of our `master.js` file - can you confirm that this file is properly requested and received by your browser (perhaps by using a sniffer or [http proxy](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/))?

Just edit your question to provide the answers, if you can.  Or enter the [chat room](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/62725/js-errors-and-broken-site-features) that [rchern](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/140548/rchern) linked to.

Comment: I just came back to check meta after taking a break and the javascript error was gone; I also found again the notification bar that notified me about the `Disciplined` badge I obtained. I'm using Firefox v3.6.8

Comment: @Kop very strange, but I'm glad that everything is working.  Let us know if it happens again.