# Are answers ever deleted permanently?

Tags: support, deleted-answers

I can see my deleted answers. Will they ever be purged from the system, either manually or automatically? Does this kind of "deleted post cleanup" occur periodically, or will all deleted answers typically remain in the system until the end of time?

Comment: You might want to support [Answers quickly deleted by owner should be permanently deleted](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14117/answers-quickly-deleted-by-owner-should-be-permanently-deleted).

Comment: @Arjan did that already. But just wanted to know if questions are even deleted permanently ever.

Comment: @hammar no I'm not asking whether I can do it. I'm asking whether they are ever deleted or not by someone else without me requesting to.

Comment: Nope, they'll remain in the system till the end of time.

Comment: Any particular reason _why_ you want to know? Lasse's answer covers the question itself.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

At the moment, content posted on Stack Overflow is never deleted, except if you plead to The Team and have them exercise their SQL magic directly on the databases.

Not only can *you* see your own deleted posts, but all 10K+ rep users can see them as well.

So no, they're not automatically deleted in any way or at any time.

Comment: As an aside: not sure if that needs plain SQL magic; it seems the developers [have magic buttons](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86195/who-has-the-privilege-to-delete-a-revision) on these sites!

Comment: As an aside: [there's also](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78048/auto-deleting-old-unanswered-zero-score-questions-after-a-year) auto-removal of negatively voted unanswered old questions after 30 days, and auto-removal of old unanswered zero score questions with very few views, after a year. I assume these are soft-deleted too, but *maybe* these are deleted permanently?

Comment: Thats just sad.

Comment: Sha Dow Wiz Ard [just confirmed](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78048/auto-deleting-old-unanswered-zero-score-questions-after-a-year#comment377336_78048) that auto-removals are soft-deletions too.

Comment: This is against the General Data Protection Regulation (GDPR) rules! I'm not a lawyer, but this means that this interface is illegal to be use as much as I understand.

Comment: No, GDPR is intended to protect people. When you contribute content to these sites you are giving these sites the right to that content. You can, however, be asked to be disassociated with the content, in which case your personal  information will be removed.

Comment: @Ronen Ariely uhm, GDPR only applies to personal information,
which means that the law is absolutely not applicable on SE!
Yep, the only thing they really have to delete as far as I understand it (and I had 2 1,5-hour lectures about it) is the email address in your account if you delete it

Comment: True but not accurate @Hobbamok . How come it can be true but not accurate?!? Well it is true as general sentence but not being able to delete your messages means that you cannot delete it if you mistakenly add personal information.

Comment: No one is anonymized when contributing to SE nor publication are endorsed by SE...  just because we agreed to give the "right" of the content to SE does not permit to SE to bypass GDPR! this is not facebook/google in term of content otherwise SE would have some legal troubles because the current situation is at the limit of legality if not illegal... i don't really get the point here because the questioned data are not really useful to SE... at least we still have the possibility to delete our account all together