# Is deleted spam normally visible to 10k users?

Tags: discussion, deleted-answers, spam, 10k-tools

I've come across a [deleted answer that is obvious spam](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3510155/710446): it's nothing more than a link to a site selling high-end purses. The answer has been deleted, but it's still visible to me as a 10k user. It makes me mildly nervous to have a link to a suspicious site sitting there where I might accidentally click on it. (Usually I've got pretty good aim with a mouse, but I have made mistakes before.)

What is SE's policy here? Do the mods have a readily-available mechanism for purging posts from view of 10k users? Note that this answer dates back to August 2010, so I understand that any such mechanism -- if it exists today -- might not have existed back then. Maybe more recent spam-handling procedure prevents this from happening?

Also, is there a verb to describe such an action? The best I can think to use is "obliterate", "super-delete", or "delete it harder".

Comment: I believe destroyed is the usual term

Comment: Discount Gucci Handbags?

Comment: Posts don't get destroyed.

Comment: @mikeTheLiar As far as I can tell from the post, these Gucci bags are not even discounted.

Comment: The term in programming is just "hard delete" vs. the "soft delete" that is normally used.

Comment: On deleted answers/questions, shouldn't links be un-hyperlinked, i.e. still show the URL of the intended link, so it's there for demonstrative purposes, but it shouldn't be clickable.

Comment: Closely related: [Are spam answers ever deleted permanently?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/121585)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> The answer has been deleted, but it's still visible to me as a 10k user.

Yes - and to mods as well.

---

> What is SE's policy here?

Same as all other deleted content - it is soft deleted.

> Do the mods have a readily-available mechanism for purging posts from view of 10k users?

No, they don't. But they *can* edit it out.

---

There has been a recent change, where a placeholder message will come up on deleted answers that have at least one spam flag that was resolved as helpful, which replaces the answer text and contains a link to the answer revisions (so 10k users can still see the answer if needed).

Comment: I sometimes see team members mentioning they can hard delete revisions (e.g. to remove any trace to sensitive/private information like passwords), isn't that such a "readily-available mechanism"?

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd - only if there _are_ revisions. And even then, not to be done lightly.

Comment: Sure not lightly... but if you nuke the only revision doesn't it cause the whole post to go poof? ;)

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd - Not sure it does. We still have post histories and other items that require cleanups. One way or another - destroying revisions != hard deleting questions and is not the same as a "readily-available mechanism" (which, if we ever do implement can be abused).

Comment: Thanks, editing seems to be the ideal solution here. I don't mind seeing it and letting it remain visible in the edit history, I just don't want it where I can easily click it.